# Is there a way to create a redux based reactJS app with a signle command like create-react-app

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to reactJS and want to deep learn it. I started practicing reactJS after briefly going through its [documentation provided by Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html).

---

I started working with

> `npm init` 
>   [editing `package.json` with `babel`, `webpack`, `react`, etc. installations]

After quite a long practice on this drill, I get to know about the tool

> `create-react-app [name]`

provided by Facebook itself for the ease of developers, new to react. That was a moment of relief for me.

Now I am working on redux pattern and it contains a lot of configurations and directory maintenance.

Is there any tool that makes it easy to set up a skeleton a redux react app?

Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is no good direct package that create react redux boiler plate. You might wanna have a look at [this](https://medium.com/@notrab/getting-started-with-create-react-app-redux-react-router-redux-thunk-d6a19259f71f). He used create-react-app and also configures redux very nicely.